# How do I handle a Disk Bottleneck?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am encountering a bottleneck when training in **reading** on my HDD.

1. It is not obvious to me why my disk is being used so heavily whilst training my NN
2. nor why it chose the specific drive (Disk 0: D)

Setup and Disk usage when training:

- Disk 0 (D:) 100% (reading) - Slow HHD
- Disk 1 (C:) 0% - Fast SSD
- Disk 2 (E:) 0% - Slow HHD (>os.path.dirname(sys.executable) - 'E:\Anaconda')

I am assuming it chose the Disk 0 by default given it is Disk 0 (motherboard configuration); is that not the case? and can I change it to Disk 1 somehow besides switching cables and how may it impact performance?

My GPU(5%) and CPU(30%) are barely in use and I have encountered bottlenecks with CPU feeding the data to the GPU, is there some place where it defaults to write on disk 0 when RAM(93%) is low?

TF:2.1, Windows 10. Jupyter Notebook:

```
#**TEXT TOKENIZATION**

#Model:
epochs = 4
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(1000,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=1024,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1,
                shuffle=True,
                use_multiprocessing=True,
                validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: Windows 10? Are you sure it's not something to do with the damnable windows update?

Comment: As your code shouldn't have anything to do with hdd. The only other thing I can think of is Disk Fragmentation. As CUDA is a pretty big library.

Comment: Windows 10 indeed. Possibly, you mean paging?

Comment: No, I don't use Windows anymore but there should be something called Disk Defragmentor

Comment: The HDD is only in use when training.

Comment: Also, how about `use_multiprocessing=False`

Comment: Yes, I have tried with False, no diff.

Comment: `model.fit` doesn't use HDD. Beside try to defrag the disk all I can do is suggest you to use Ubuntu instead, but that's not the answer. Sorry can't help more than that

Comment: Try defragging first, probably couple of hours if your disk is read/write often

Comment: Appreciate it, I have too many issues using Windows, most recently apex fp16. But I need the RDP functionality. Besides Windows will add a linux VM soon to it.

Comment: Ok, turns out my paging file is not allocated for my SSD, but for the D: drive. For those similar problems try the following: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10,36929.html

Comment: Glad to hear that. But if you're going to do many NN training after this, Ubuntu might be better option. Win10 reserve some VRAM so you have only 70 something % you can use, and you can't use multiprocessing which fasten pre-processing speed

Comment: I get that, also, do you follow the CPU hardware meta for such a system? I think a Threadripper (64pcie) is decent, but that certain libraries are throttled when not using Intel...

Comment: My budget only allow for a single GPU so more than 16 lanes won't be any use. One thing really important is that Intel has MKL library which make math operation very fast. As far as I know it's several times faster than what you can use in AMD

Comment: Thanks buddy, I came to the same conclusion. The choice mostly depends on the number of GPU's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The OS is using Paging when the RAM spills over.
2. Processor list->Performance->RAM: Read virtual/Allocated RAM... resides in your Disk drive, and in the case of the wrong disk it can be changed in Windows by the following:

System->Advanced->Performance->Advanced->Change

Reassign and then restart.

Source: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10,36929.html